# Complex differentiable iff map is Frechet differentiable and Cauchy Riemann equations hold

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

[image]

Suppose $\ f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is complex differentiable at $z=x+iy \in U$. Then $\lim_{v \rightarrow 0} \frac{\left|\ f(z+v)-f(z)-f'(z)\ \right|}{|v|}=0$. Let $v=v_1+iv_2$.

$f'(z)\ v=(g+ih)(v_1+iv_2)=(gv_1-hv_2)+i(hv_1+gv_2)$. Now I am stuck.

The converse is probably easier once I have done the above.

Note: Complex differentiation has not even been defined for me.

Comment: which book was used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual trick is: if
$$\lim_{z\to c}\frac{f(z)-f(c)}{z-c}$$
exists, then the limits on the subsets $\Re z = \Re c$ and $\Im z = \Im c$ exists an are equal. And in such limits will appear the partial derivatives of $g$ and $h$.

EDIT:
$$\eqalign{f'(z_0)
&= \lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}
 = \lim_{x\to x_0}\left(\frac{g(x,y_0)-g(x_0,y_0)}{x-x_0} + i\,\frac{h(x,y_0)-h(x_0,y_0)}{x-x_0}\right)\cr
&= g_x(x_0,y_0) + ih_x(x_0,y_0);\cr
}$$
$$\eqalign{f'(z_0)
&= \lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}
 = \lim_{y\to y_0}\left(\frac{g(x_0,y)-g(x_0,y_0)}{i(y-y_0)} + i\,\frac{h(x_0,y)-h(x_0,y_0)}{i(y-y_0)}\right)\cr
&= \lim_{y\to y_0}\left(-i\,\frac{g(x_0,y)-g(x_0,y_0)}{y-y_0} + \frac{h(x_0,y)-h(x_0,y_0)}{y-y_0}\right)\cr
&=  -ig_y(x_0,y_0) + h_y(x_0,y_0).\cr
}$$
An this implies
$$
g_x(x_0,y_0)  = h_y(x_0,y_0),\qquad h_x(x_0,y_0) = -g_y(x_0,y_0).
$$

Answer (score 3):

The function $f:\ {\mathbb C}\to{\mathbb C}$ is complex differentable at $0$ **iff** the limit
$$\lim_{z\to0}{f(z)-f(0)\over z}=:C=A+iB\in{\mathbb C}$$
exists. This is **equivalent** with the fact
$$f(z)-f(0)=C\>z+r(z)\tag{1}$$
whereby ${\displaystyle{r(z)\over z}=0}$ when $z\to0$, or
$$\lim_{z\to 0}{|r(z)|\over |z|}=0\ .\tag{2}$$
Separating $(1)\wedge(2)$ into real and imaginary parts, and writing ${\bf z}=(x,y)$ instead of $z$, as well as   ${\bf f}=(g,h)$ instead of  $f$, we see that $(1)\wedge(2)$ is **equivalent** with
$$\eqalign{
g(x,y)&=Ax-By+r_1({\bf z}) \cr
h(x,y)&=Bx+Ay+r_2({\bf z})\ , \cr}\tag{3}$$
whereby
$$\lim_{{\bf z}\to 0}{|r_k({\bf z})|\over |{\bf z}|}={\bf 0}\qquad(k=1,\>2)\ .\tag{4}$$
But $(3)\wedge(4)$ are saying that the vector-valued function ${\bf f}$ is differentiable at ${\bf 0}$ and that the four partial derivatives of ${\bf f}$ at ${\bf 0}$ are related in the described way.

Comment: Why did you compute the derivatives at $0$?

Comment: In order to understand what the derivative means under the two different interpretations we may fix the point where we differentiate once and for all, since all pertinent constructions are translation invariant.